# Not able to Call a webservice from VISTA

Tags: c#

We have a webservice deployed and calling it from Windows application, it is working for everbody except for 3 users who is using VISTA operating machine when they try to access the webservice from application they get the below error

"A Required prevelege is not held by the client"

however they are able to access the webservice ASMX URL directly from browser with their credentials.

Can anyone tell me to figure out this issue

Answer (score 1):

Try running the application as an administrative user and check it the problem persists.

Comment: Actually this is a VSTO application running on EXCEL 2007.
How can run it in administrator?

Comment: Try running the Host application with elevated privileges.

Comment: How can i run the Excel in Administrator

Comment: Which version of office are you using?